# /run in Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, directory-structure

I'm running Debian Squeeze (6.0.1) on a NAS (LinkStation, mipsel). I installed [minidlna](http://packages.debian.org/sid/minidlna) from unstable and noticed the daemon won't start because it can't create `/run/minidlna`.

After a little googling I found http://wiki.debian.org/ReleaseGoals/RunDirectory. This somewhat explains what's happening, and for now I just made a symlink to make stuff work:

```
ln -s /var/run /run
```

I'm a little afraid this isn't a good way to solve the problem. What would be the proper way of getting `/run` on Debian Squeeze? What problems could be caused by just symlinking like I did?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to adapt your system to that app?

Wouldn't be more logical to adapt that "minidlna" (whatever is it) to Debian?

Probably you just need to edit the minidlna start script (it will be located at /etc/init.d/ if it is a daemon) to use the system's /var/run rather than creating a /run symlink.

I understand from your question that "minidlna" is a deb package. Then once you solved the issue in the init script, report your fix back to the package maintainer.

Comment: the OP installed an *unstable* package on a *stable* system, so this does not qualify as a bug.  There's no [`minidlna` package](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=minidlna) for stable, no backport either.

Comment: but there should be a maintainer of that package if it is a package. And I'm sure that person would love to hear feedback for his work. By no means I've said that that could be a bug in debian. But indeed there's a bug in the package as it is.

Comment: You're right, that's probably a better way to get a healthy Debian stable system...(not sure if there's a reason against the stable package, though) -- [the package in PTS](http://packages.qa.debian.org/m/minidlna.html)

Comment: @hmontoliu: The problem is just what sr_ said in their first comment. In *unstable/testing* `/run` must be used, while in *stable* it doesn't yet exist. I can, of course edit the init script, but that's bad practice on APT-installed packages. Have a +1 for pointing out I should rather do this than symlink `/var/run`—but I'm still looking for a more proper solution. This would get very clumsy if I had a lot of testing/unstable packages.

Comment: My above comment is no longer true; [there's at least an unofficial `minidlna` package for Squeeze now](http://blog.steve.org.uk/minidlna_is_now_packaged.html).